# ListBox for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a good and easy to use solution for creating MultiSelectLists in MVC for many-to-many relationships.

I have this following example code and it works fine, but it just takes a lot of code.  It would be cool if it were shorter, smarter, or even made generic somehow, so that it's easy to create `MultiSelectList`s in future projects.

**My Database using Entity Framework Code First:**

Books, and authors, where one book, can have multiple authors.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Allows multiple authors for one book.
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int[] SelectedBooks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);
        if (author == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewData["BooksList"] = new MultiSelectList(db.Books, "Id", "Name", author.Books.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray());

        return View(author);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Author author)
    {
        ViewData["BooksList"] = new MultiSelectList(db.Books, "Id", "Name", author.SelectedBooks);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Update all the other values.
            Author edit = db.Authors.Find(author.Id);
            edit.Name = auther.Name;

        //------------    
            //Make adding items possible
            if (edit.Books == null) edit.Books = new List<Book>();

            //Remove the old, add the new, instead of finding out what to remove, and what to add, and what to leave be.
            foreach (var item in edit.Books.ToList())
            {
                edit.Books.Remove(item);
            }
            foreach (var item in author.SelectedBooks)
            {
                edit.Books.Add(db.Books.Find(item));
            }
        //------------- 
        // This is the code i want to simplify
        // Would be cool with a generic extention method like this:
        // db.ParseNewEntities(edit.Books, author.SelectedBooks);
        // I just don't know how to code it.  



            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(author);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @Html.ListBox("SelectedBooks",(MultiSelectList)ViewData["BooksList"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using ViewData I might consider using ViewBag (if on MVC 3 and above) or even wrapping Author within a ViewModel.  That what you won't need the cast on the view (if using a viewModel).

Otherwise your MultiSelectList code is only one line.  Don't see you getting much better than that :)

Your viewmodel might look like

```
public class AuthorViewModel 
{
   public Author BookAuthor { get; set; }
   public MultiSelectList BookList { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Author author = db.Authors.Find(id);
    if (author == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new AuthorViewModel 
    {
       BookAuthor = author;
       BookList = new MultiSelectList(db.Books, "Id", "Name", author.Books.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray());
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Your view will need to be typed to the view model and you could then write

```
Html.ListBox("SelectedBooks",Model.BookList);
```

I'm not 100% sure then if you need to re-bind it back on the post if there is a problem.  If you do, I would consider doing that after the Model.IsValid unless of course your "Index" action usings the ViewData["BookList"] value?

EDIT:
Ok, what about this then.

```
    internal class BookEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Book>
    {
        public bool Equals(Book x, Book y)
        {
            return x.Id == y.Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Book obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then your code in the Post will be:

```
    // Take the values common to both lists based on the EqualityComparer
    edit.Books.Union(author.SelectedBooks, new BookEqualityComparer ());
```

And I would consider making the Books DbSet lazy loaded.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    private DbSet<Book> _books;
    public DbSet<Book> Books 
    { 
       get { return _books ?? (_book = new DbSet<Book>()); } // TBH not 100% sure you can set DbSet like this but worth a shot 
       set { _books = value; } 
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: True, but i actually don't mind casting the values, the real is in the [HttpPost] method.. I've updated the question with some inline comments to show you what part i'm interested in shortening :)

Comment: @BjarkeCK Union might be an option you could consider.  I've updated my answer for it's usage

Comment: Wow there's a lot of unfamiliar code there, lazy load and IEqualityComparer. i willd need to do some research on those, thanks :)

Comment: But i can see that it is not generic, can you make it generic ?

Comment: Instead of IEqualityComparer<Book> just go IEqualityComparer<T> ? I'll research, then ask.. :p

Comment: @BjarkeCK Just realised that Lazy might not work in this instance as you can't set the variable. However is still good reading to know it's around.  Updated my code slightly